# Jenkins Validation Against Gerrit Master/Slave Setup

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

We are currently running gerrit 2.7 in a master/slave setup, i.e. the master is configured to replicate the repos to a gerrit slave with no UI enabled.

The idea is that Jenkins can pull from the slaves and not add load to the UI serving master.

The problem I ran into was that using the gerrit plugin in Jenkins to run validations would get triggered, and if it pulled from slave, the refs would not yet be replicated and validation would fail.

Obviously, if Jenkins were to pull from master, no problem, but doing that would defeat the purpose...

I was wondering if anyone knows whether I can point the Jenkins gerrit plugin to the gerrit slave and if that works. Also open for any other ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `remote.<name>.replicationDelay` in `replication.config` to `0`. This should remove the default delay causing your problems.

Alternatively you should consider using your slave repo as reference instead (provided the replication slave is on the same physical machine as your jenkins/jenkins slave), but still pull from the master. That way, control would still be with your master gerrit (resulting in a slight load), but the bulk of the data transfer would fall to the replication job.

Better still, most of the time, your jenkins jobs would not need to pull anything at all, because the objects are already there. This reduces build times as well as required space for your jobs.

Even if your replication was lagging behind, that way you would loose nothing, because in that special case, the missing objects would simply be received from master instead.

Comment: I like the idea of using gerrit relication to the build slave's reference repo. That might solve a variety of issues, except that I worry a little about the network load - we have over 100 build slaves.

Comment: In that case, consider placing your reference repos on nfs shares (or cifs when on windows). I had a similar setup in place in an earlier project with around 20 slaves. I see no reason it should not work with 100.

Comment: Just another useful point: Gerrit Trigger Plugin 2.12 (currently in Beta) contains a feature to allow to block a build until gerrit replication is completed (https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/commit/ab429cf8f154995c1def119940f22dc18f71be57)